# How to cancel the automatic turn on mode of the computer

Tags: windows-7

Good time. My computer is mini hp model. When I turn off the computer or put it in sleep mode, it turns on automatically after a few seconds. How do you think I can fix it?!

Comment: Go to BIOS and look for Wake ON ...  Something there turned ON.

Comment: That it woke after "I turn off the computer..." leads me to believe it was not actually being **turned off**. Try shutting it by pressing Windows+R key,  type `shutdown /s /t 0` and press Enter key. If it wakes after that, there is an issue.

Comment: Hello. If it doesn't work, what's the problem?
Is it possible that the settings are messed up?!
How can I contact you?

Answer (score 0):

If you put it to sleep, then any keyboard or mouse activity (even inadvertent) will wake it.
If you power it off, and it started spontaneously, then there is a BIOS setting at work, boot the system to BIOS and look for power options.

Answer (score 0):

Force Shutdown

To perform a Force Shutdown, type in

`Shutdown –s –f`

To clear him up a little if he is lost in some kind of a loop if that does not fix you should probably visit BIOS and see if something like  **wake on lan** or **wake on power** etc. is turned on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello. If it doesn't work, what's the problem?
Is it possible that the settings are messed up?!
How can I contact you?